# Main services inaccessible from view helper factories?

Tags: zend-framework2

When I create a factory for a view helper ('view_helpers' configuration key), the service locator passed to the factory does not have any services registered with the main service manager ('service_manager' configuration key). That means the helper factory cannot use, for example, configuration (`$serviceLocator->get('Configuration'` fails). What is the recommended way to access such services in view helper factory context?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Configuration');
```

This is because the view helpers and controller plugins do not recieve the main Service Locator. For example one of my controller plugin receives an instance of `Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager`.